# How can I handle duplicate data in Elasticsearch?

Tags: lucene, search-engine, elasticsearch

I have used parent & child mapping to normalize data but as far as I understand there is no way to get any fields from _parent document.

Here is the mapping of my index:

```
{
 "mappings": {
    "building": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "flat": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "building"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "room": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "flat"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "floor": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I'm trying to find the best way of storing `flat_name` and `building_name` in room type. I won't query these fields but I should be able to get them when I query other fields like `floor`.

There will be millions of rooms and I don't have much memory so I suspect that these duplicate values may cause out of memory. For now, `flat_name` and `building_name` fields are has `"index": "no"` property and I turned on compression for _source field.

Do you have any efficient suggestion for avoiding duplicate values like querying multiple queries or hacky way to get fields from _parent document or denormalized data is the only way to handle this kindle of problem?

Comment: maybe this post is interesting for you http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/