# Statistical Facets for distinct Results to avoid double counting

Tags: elasticsearch

We have use case where we have query which can bring duplicate results and we are running  Statistical Facets on them.

This results gives wrong results as query results in duplicate documents. Is there any way we can avoid duplicate counting?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is the example query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "Latitude": {
                    "from": "0",
                    "to": "19150"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "Longitude": {
                    "from": "0",
                    "to": "19150"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "contractsearch",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "Id": {
                        "gt": "0"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "has_child": {
                      "type": "exposuregraphsearch",
                      "query": {
                        "terms": {
                          "CedantExposureIdList": [
                            "706341"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "Latitude": {
      "statistical": {
        "fields": [
          "Latitude"
        ]
      }
    },
    "Longitude": {
      "statistical": {
        "fields": [
          "Longitude"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: any responses? please?

Comment: see it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060845/how-can-i-handle-duplicate-data-in-elasticsearch